# warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]

Tags: c, wchar-t

I want to have an Array of the Greek alphabet and this is what I do:

```
wchar_t pcletters[30] = {'α' , 'ά' , 'β' , 'γ' , 'δ' , 'ε' , 'ζ' , 'η', 'θ' , 'ι' , 'κ' , 'λ' , 'μ' , 'ν','ξ' , 'ο' , 'π' , 'ρ' , 'σ' , 'τ' , 'υ' , 'φ' , 'χ' , 'ψ' , 'ω', 'έ' , 'ή' , 'ί' , 'ό' , 'ύ' , 'ώ'} ;
```

I also include  `<locale.h>` and have a line `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "") .`

However I get the warning  warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]. 
Moreover when I get to check if one of this letters is in a user input by doing :

```
if (userword[i] == pcletters[j]) {//do stuff}
```

it does not seem to work. 
-Why do I get this warning ? 
-Is there a way to change pcletters in a way to be able to compare 
the `userword[i] == pcletters[j]`

Note: `userword` is defined like this: `wchar_t userword[40]` .

Comment: I think you need `wchar_t pcletters[30] = {L'α', L'ά', L'β', L'γ', ...`

Comment: I think the greek alphabet is a multibyte char alphabet, meaning one `char` is not enough to hold one letter. Same goes for the spanish reversed-question-mark (which could lead to a security failure for addslashes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use wide character literals:

```
wchar_t pcletters[30] = {L'α' , ...
                         ^
```

Note that this will only work on platforms where the letters you are writing are a single wide character; this should work on Windows, where `wchar_t` is UCS-2.

Comment: ℑ '  '     .

Comment: @Hi-Angel yes, this is specifically for characters that fit into a single wchar_t on the target platform.

Comment: @ecatmur even in UTF16 are things that doesn't fit into two bytes, [like surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF). I'm inclined to think that `wchar_t` usage is a bad idea. AFAIK C++ standard doesn't provide tools to work with Unicode, so the work have to be done with aside libs. As for the minimal support — I think that multi-byte characters should rather be stored as a string.

Comment: @Hi-Angel anyone who's processing general text will have to deal with extended plane and even multi-codepoint characters sooner or later - thank Unicode for emoji. But I'm not sure how this is relevant to this question.

Comment: @ecatmur this is relevant because everyone who got here from a search engine would think of `wchar_t` as a panacea, when it isn't. The question already have 3k views. So I thought that someone should leave a warning here ☺

Comment: @Hi-Angel, I just tested on my compiler (gcc 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04 under Linux Mint 20.2) that `wchar_t` will hold even `U+2F9F4` (as far as I can tell, the highest Unicode character with a glyph). On my platform, `sizeof(whcar_t) == 4`.